# Docusign - get the internal document id for an envelope

Tags: docusignapi

The documents we send out for signature all map to our internal document system. These documents have id values like 101275804, 101275806, etc.

Right now, the document id we use is set to ordinal values, 1, 2, etc. and we have these large numbers as document fields. We need to have a way to map our documents to their document id so that we can fetch each one individually and get back the right document.

Can we use numbers like 101275804 as the document id or is it possible to get the document id that Docusign uses internally for storing the documents? I don't see anything in the api for getting that internal value.

Comment: Could we use a guid for a document id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DocumentId` needs to be a positive integer (no GUID allowed). Yes, you can set 101275804, 101275806, etc values as `documentId` when creating envelopes, and same documentId will be used to retrieve the documents back from Docusign via GET /documents/{id} endpoint [Get Documents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/). API Call to create envelope using documentId:

```
"documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "<Base64>",
      "documentId": "101275804",
      "fileExtension": "pdf",
      "name": "Sample Doc"
    }
  ]
```

To retrieve above document, you make below call

```
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/<accountId>/envelopes/<envelopeId>/documents/101275804
```

Comment: I didn't think a guid could be used, but I wanted to confirm it. Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 1):

You can also store your system's document id as metadata for the document itself. This is a "document field" in the DocuSign system. See parameter `documentFields` in the `document` object. See https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#definitions